# Why do icons have different colors in NavigationBar and TableView in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I am aware of tintcolor property of `UINavigationBar` and it is set to its default in my project.
This way the icons on this bar have blue color.

But when I add same icons in `UITableViewCell`s, they are of grey (original png) color.

Is there a way to make it have same color as the ones on the Navigation Bar?

Comment: set the tint color of for the imageView to blue will fix help u.

Comment: That I tried, when created the image, in ViewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear, but did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS7  you can use a new property in order to redraw an UIImage so you can have it with the same color as the tint color.

Here is an example:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
backButtonImage = [backButtonImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

Finally you will need to set either the `setTintColor` property of the object where you adding that `UIImage` or the property in the whole project.

Hope this helps!